# File content into dictionary

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I need to turn this file content into a dictionary, so that every key in the dict is a name of a movie and every value is the name of the actors that plays in it inside a set.

Example of file content:

```
Brad Pitt, Sleepers, Troy, Meet Joe Black, Oceans Eleven, Seven, Mr & Mrs Smith
Tom Hanks, You have got mail, Apollo 13, Sleepless in Seattle, Catch Me If You Can
Meg Ryan, You have got mail, Sleepless in Seattle
Diane Kruger, Troy, National Treasure
Dustin Hoffman, Sleepers, The Lost City
Anthony Hopkins, Hannibal, The Edge, Meet Joe Black, Proof
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
res_dict = {}

with open('my_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        my_list = [item.strip() for item in line.split(',')]
        res_dict[my_list[0]] = my_list[1:]  # To make it a set, use: set(my_list[1:])
```

**Explanation:**

[`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) is used to split each line to form a list using `,` separator

[`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) is used to remove spaces around each element of the previous list

When you use [`with statement`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with), you do not need to close your file explicitly.

`[item.strip() for item in line.split(',')]` is called a [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

**Output:**

```
>>> res_dict
{'Diane Kruger': ['Troy', 'National Treasure'], 'Brad Pitt': ['Sleepers', 'Troy', 'Meet Joe Black', 'Oceans Eleven', 'Seven', 'Mr & Mrs Smith'], 'Meg Ryan': ['You have got mail', 'Sleepless in Seattle'], 'Tom Hanks': ['You have got mail', 'Apollo 13', 'Sleepless in Seattle', 'Catch Me If You Can'], 'Dustin Hoffman': ['Sleepers', 'The Lost City'], 'Anthony Hopkins': ['Hannibal', 'The Edge', 'Meet Joe Black', 'Proof']}
```

Comment: Some SO users believe that questions that don't show any research effort should not be answered.

Comment: I am sorry @vaultah, but when we see something like "I dont even know where to start" I think that we should help!

Comment: to turn every dict value to a set do i just iterate over the items and use the set() method?

Comment: @RanElgiser yes, that's would be enough!

Comment: Take a look at the edit (`# To make it a set, use: set(my_list[1:])`)

Comment: @ettanany kinda new here, what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:

```
line = "a, b, c, d"
result = {}
names = line.split(", ")
actor = names[0]
movies = names[1:]
result[actor] = movies
```